# Allowing localhost to relay everywhere in Exchange 2010

Tags: php, iis, exchange, exchange-2010

I'm trying to set up PHP on a Windows Server 2008 machine running both IIS7 and Exchange 2010, and no matter what I do, it will not relay messages outside of the domain.

I.e.: I telnet to `localhost 25`, do the `HELO/MAIL FROM:/RCPT TO:` dance. Any domain ending in my local domain works; any with elsewhere as domain receive a `550 5.7.1 Unable to Relay` error.

If I set `*` as an Accepted Domain, everything starts working, mails relay, all of it works great. However, this is clearly problematic -- I'd really like to not turn my client's server into an open relay (verified via Abuse.net's relay checking tool).

**How does one enable open relaying from *only* localhost in Exchange 2010?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new receive connector. Set the scope to 127.0.0.1,check the box that says "Externally secured", and allow anonymous connections as well as Exchange Servers. You'd do that in EMS like this:

> new-receiveconnector -name LOCALHOST -Usage Custom -authmechanism externalauthoritative -enabled $true -fqdn mail.domain.com -remoteipranges 127.0.0.1 -permissiongroups anonymoususers,ExchangeServers -bindings 127.0.0.1:25

Comment: No dice; still get the same error.

Comment: Try it with the updated EMS command. I just successfully tested it in my lab running Exchange 2010 SP1

Comment: Also make sure you don't have another receive connector with the same scope.

Comment: That totally worked. And I did have a receive connector with the same scope -- apparently there was a SBS Fax Sharepoint there too. Deleting that enabled your command to work beautifully.

Comment: Thankyou thankyou thankyou @Jason for the note about turning off the other connector in the same scope.  24 hours of frustration solved!